# WiFi on Ubuntu 19.04 is insanely slow compared to Windows 10

Tags: wireless, 19.04

I have just freshly installed Ubuntu 19.04 on a partition on my hard drive and am dual booting with Windows 10. I ran internet speed tests on both operating systems and got a download rate of 104mb/s on Windows 10. However, on Ubuntu (version 19.04) I am only getting 4mb/s. I’m not sure if this is a driver problem or a bug with Ubuntu itself.
Help me please!

WiFi card info:
lspci-

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d0
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d1
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d3
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15db
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15dc
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e8
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e9
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ea
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15eb
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ec
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ed
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ee
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ef
01:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43d5 (rev 01)
01:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c8 (rev 01)
01:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c6 (rev 01)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
02:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
02:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
02:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
02:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c8)
08:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15de
08:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15df
08:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e0
08:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e1
08:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e3
09:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 61)
```

sudo lshw -class network-

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 01
       serial: 18:31:bf:c5:d8:7d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=5.0.0-15-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:57 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcd00000-fcd03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 15
       serial: 40:b0:76:42:a8:45
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:35 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fcc04000-fcc04fff memory:fcc00000-fcc03fff
```